# How to compare two tables without unique identifier in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, comparison

[image]

I have two tables that have the same structure without a unique identifier. How to compare these two tables

I try to use row numbers to compare them. The code is as the following

```
WITH source AS  
(  
     SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Customer Account    address) AS RowN,   
         Customer Account address
     FROM 
         old
)  

WITH target AS  
(  
     SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Customer Account    address) AS RowN,   
         Customer Account address
     FROM 
         New
)  

SELECT 
    s.address, t.address 
FROM
    source s
JOIN
    traget t ON s.RowN = t.RowN
WHERE
    s.Customer != t.Customer
    OR s.Account != t.Account
    OR s.address != t.address
```

Except result:

```
s.address   t.address
---------------------
BB1         BB2
```

But I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'

Microsoft SQL Server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Comment: Remove the second `WITH`, you only need 1 when you start defining CTEs, and then you comma delimit them (which is also missing).

Comment: And if you `ORDER BY ` a list of columns, you need to comma separate them, too

Comment: `Customer    Account address` isn't valid either. In truth, the above is riddled with syntax errors.

Comment: The logic here is reasonable but the code is filled with syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing alot of commas ;)

```
WITH source AS  
(  
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Customer ,Account, address) AS RowN,   
    Customer,    Account ,address
FROM old
)  
, target AS  
(  
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Customer, Account ,address) AS RowN,   
    Customer,    Account, address
FROM New
)  

Select s.address , t.address 
from source s
join traget t on s.RowN =t.RowN
where s.Customer <> t.Customer
or s.Account <> t.Account
or s.address <> t.address
```

Comment: This is still missing a lot of commas. Look at the order by clauses. ;)

Comment: @SeanLange lol it was , thank you ;)

Comment: Hi eshirvana, Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

You can, actually, work with the `EXCEPT` table operator:
Like here:

```
WITH 
old_table(cust,accnt,addr) AS (
            SELECT 'AAAA',101,'AA1'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'BBBB',102,'BB1'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'CCCC',102,'BB1'
)
,
new_table AS (
            SELECT 'AAAA',101,'AA1'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'BBBB',102,'BB1'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'CCCC',102,'BB2'
)
(
SELECT * FROM old_table
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM new_table
)
UNION ALL 
(
SELECT * FROM new_table
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM old_table
)
;
-- out  cust | accnt | addr 
-- out ------+-------+------
-- out  CCCC |   102 | BB1
-- out  CCCC |   102 | BB2
```

Comment: Hi Marcothesane, My tables have a million records. do we have a way to compare these two tables